# Which heat pad content materials will keep me warm the longest?

Tags: heat, specific-heat

I am trying to find a good heating pad/bag for myself that keeps me warm for as long as possible (nonelectrical, heated once, then used until it gets cold). The classic is a hot water bottle, and according to wikipedia

> Liquid water has one of the highest specific heat capacities among common substances, about 4184 J⋅kg−1⋅K−1 at 20 °C

this is already good compared to [other common materials](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/specific-heat-capacity-d_391.html).

Throught the internet, other materials for heating bags/pad are sold. Among them:

- watery gel ([medical heat/cold pads](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00AZ72XA8))
- different types of grains/seeds (rice, wheat, [buckwheat](https://www.amazon.com/Lavender-Microwave-Shoulders-Relaxation-Aromatherapy), peas, cherry stones)
- [sand](https://www.amazon.de/Physiotherm-Lava-Cushion-Fango-Spelt/dp/B088RF6GC7)
- [moor mud](https://www.amazon.de/-/en/Vybelle-Cushion-Microwave-Fango-Large/dp/B0B4P58VQ6)

And I often find opinions about them, like

- heat pads are better than water bottles
- grain/seed pillows are better than water bottles
- moor mud pillows keep warm the longest
  and so on. But these are bare statments, I could not find explanations of any of these claims. So from the little I know about physics I thought it might have to do with specific heat capacity of these materials. But those cannot be found anywhere. Of course they will not have ONE value; all listed materials are material mixes so they would have a range, but I could not find any range either.

**Can anyone provide such values/ranges?**

**Or are there other things to consider beside heat capacity?**

Comment: Not all the warming is based on heat capacity, some is based on active release of heat, activated on demand. // For the former, not only capacity, but also shape of contact surface, initial surface temperature and rate of heat provision(heat conductivity) are important.

Comment: You state, "nonelectrical, heated once, then used until it gets cold;" does that include *phase change* heat sources (\e.g., sodium acetate)? Does it exclude chemical reactions, such as rusting?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I am not trying to create my own heat pad, I merely want to buy one that one can buy on the market. I am not aware of any type of reusable heating pad that includes phase changes or chemical reactions.

Comment: @Kjara, standard operating procedure for winter camping: put a hand warmer in the sleeping bag before retiring, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/Hand-Warmers-90-Count-Activated/dp/B09P4M8DC2/, which relies on rusting, or https://www.amazon.com/Instant-Reusable-Heat-Camping-Wave/dp/B000E4C5DC/ , using phase change, (nor recommendations, just examples)